# Does System.out.println execute faster when compared to System.out.printf

Tags: java, hashmap, conditional-statements, printf, execution-time

So, I was going through a problem where I was asked to create a dictionary to store a number as key and value being a phone number. My first code couldn't execute the problem in time, whereas my second iteration did. Why did this happen?
My first Code snippet:-

```
while(sn.hasNext()){
    String s=sn.nextLine();
    System.out.printf((pb.get(s)==null)?"Not found":"%d=%s%n",s,pb.get(s));} //pb is the hashmap obj
```

My second Code:

```
while(sn.hasNext()){
    String s=sn.nextLine();
    if(pb.get(s)==null){
         System.out.println("Not found");
    else System.out.println(s+"="+pb.get(s));}
```

If I remove the conditional statement inside the System.out.printf and replace it with if else , it passes all test cases within time. Why is it so?

Comment: The execution time of the print statement itself is so trivial that it won't make any difference.

Comment: This is actually a problem from hackerrank , so while using the first one I couldnt get past 2 of the 5 cases , but once i implemented the 2nd one I got it working . also to cross check I removed printf and used println with ? operator and it still worked properly . What makes printf statement different in terms of execution time?